# Sudo-apt unable to connect to localhost:port

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, virtual-machine

for testing purposes I installed ubuntu-12.04 on an virtual machine (Oracle VM Virtualbox Manager) and now I am trying to install mysql on this machine. (I am fairly new to this..)

After logging in I use this command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but I get this error over and over:

***Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg Unable to connect to localhost:3000:***

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/116243/apt-get-update-fails-due-to-unable-to-connect-to-localhost8250-error

So I'm not sure if this post still belongs here.

Had to remove the line Acquire::http::proxy "localhost:8250/";; from /etc/apt/apt.conf